# Semantics of Captured Variables

Tags: lambda, closures

Can someone please explain the **semantics** of captured variables in the following two cases:

(1) an anonymous method (a lambda expression) that captures only instance and static (class) fields (but not local variables or parameters), and

(2) an anonymous method that captures local variables and parameters, and possibly instance and static fields.

Also, what is the relationship between closures and captured variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closure is an object (usually) that contains all captured variables used by a lambda.

If the lambda uses instance fields, it's actually implicitly capturing the `this` instance, then accessing its members.

If it only uses static fields, it doesn't have a closure at all; static fields can be accessed without context.

Comment: Does this mean that a closure will (by C# compiler) be created for both cases (1) and (2) above?

Comment: Or will this be unnecessary for (1), because there will be no variables that are local to the lambda itself?

Comment: @JoeBennett: For C#, it depends how you define "closure".  If you only capture this, the compiler can simply turn it into an instance method and create a closed delegate.  If you close over other variables, it needs to create a closure class.   See http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-3-c.html and http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-4-c.html